# Add a class angular ui tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

im using angular ui to create my tabs, and the code i inserted was the one available in the documentation:

```
<form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
            <div class="tabbable full-width-tabs">
            <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
                <uib-tab index="0" heading="Title 1">
                   text
                </uib-tab>
                <uib-tab index="1" heading="Title 2">
                    text
                </uib-tab>

            </uib-tabset>
                </div>
        </form>
```

The problem is by default the tabs with are not full width, and for this i need to add the bootstrap class nav-justified in the ul.navtabs, but since i cant access it because the code above, generates it, how can i implement a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm" justified="true">
```

Comment: Thanks, just for curiosity, how can i add custom classes do the elements?

Comment: I think classes can be added as normal way, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <uib-tabset active="activeForm" justified="true">
               <uib-tab index="0" heading="Title 1">
                   text
                </uib-tab>
                <uib-tab index="1" heading="Title 2">
                    text
                </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```